# How to correctly execte function from external file onload?

Tags: javascript, onload, strict

I have a function `myModule.myFunction` in a larger external script `mymodule.js` that is executed on `load`. Everything seems to work fine. But now I have added

```
"use strict";
```

at the top of the external script. And I get a

```
TypeError: MyModule is undefined
```

and the page stops working. So I am wondering where I did something problematic. Here is the structure of my page (unfortunately, I did not manage to produce a minimal example):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
    <!-- Some html here -->
    <script src="mymodule.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myOnload() {
            myModule.myFunction();
        }
        window.addEventListener('load', myOnload, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what the `MyModule` in `mymodule.js` looks like:

```
var myModule = (function(){
    // stuff
})();
```

Comment: @BenAston Thanks. How would I do this? I have now `var myModule = (function(){// stuff})();`

Comment: Great! That seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `myModule.js` you need to explicitly assign `myModule` to the `window` object (when using "use strict").

Change it to `window.myModule = ...`

Reason: in sloppy mode, undeclared variables are automatically added as properties on the global object. In strict mode they are not )to avoid accidental interference).

Comment: I have added it now to the `window` object rather than the `global`. Is this equivalent?

Comment: Ah turns out I am wrong - `global` is only available in NodeJS I think